# SD Card Won't Mount

Tags: usb, mount, sd-card

First off, the mount I am talking about is the SD card being able to be read/written to. So I have an Acer Aspire Switch 10 (AAS10 from hereon), Windows 8.1.
So I wanted to look at pictures I took a while ago, of course I had it on an SD card. The AAS10 doesn't have a SD card slot, so I bought a SIIG SD, M2, CF, MS, XD and TF reader. I plugged it in to the USB port through the mini USB to USB A adapter and plugged in the card, the card is a SanDisk SDHC Card 16 GB. And nothing happened, no drive showed up in the explorer, no partition, NOTHING. So I thought it was the USB hub, connected it through the built in port, still nothing. I have no idea anymore. So what should I do?!?!

Comment: Normally the sequence is the other way around.  Plug the SD card into the reader, then plug the reader into the notebook.

Comment: nothing happened

Comment: Do you have another machine to test with?